# pyodbc.Error: ('0', '[0] [unixODBC][ (786742) (SQLDriverConnectW)'

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

I'm looking to connect to a local database called climat, the attributes of which are declared in my .odbc.ini file as follows

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
climat=Ingres

[climat]
Description=ingres database climat
Driver=Ingres
Server=nu
Database=climat
ServerType=Ingres
Servername=climat
```

When I try to run a pyodbc request using the following code:

```
import pyodbc

cxn=pyodbc.connect('DSN=climat')
```

I get the error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('0', '[0] [unixODBC][ (786742) (SQLDriverConnectW)')
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Not exactly the same error, but maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16771687/3519000) helps. Cheers.

Comment: Please test your connection with plain text: connstr = 'Driver=Ingres;Server=(local);Database=iidbdb'   pyodbc.connect(connstr), To avoid any problem with configuration not found